# Imine stability in acids and bases

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

I understand that imines can be hydrolyzed in acidic medium. But what about in basic medium? Can imines still be hydrolyzed?

I have a plausible mechanism ... nitrogen's withdrawal of electron density makes the alpha proton relatively acidic; base abstracts the proton in an E2 reaction; nitrogen then takes back a proton to regenerate the base catalyst.

Is this correct? Does this actually happen?

Comment: In analogy to a carbonyl, why not attack directly at the imine's electrophilic carbon with your basic nucleophile to create a tetrahedral intermediate?  Your proposed removal of an alpha-proton does occur in the enamine formation process.